# Conversion error not return full name in category

Tags: java, vraptor

I implemented a simple post ajax in vraptor4, when send a value with conversion proble (Example: my field is integer and sent a string) the category in errors has not the fullname how said in documentation.

*"category: represents the full path of the attribute like object.attribute"*

Real example:

- field name: rodapeForm.nro
- category returned: nro

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using?

Comment: Registered issue in github https://github.com/caelum/vraptor4/issues/1013